# Prevent dependency from being installed with APT

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, java, apt

I have this script line to install all packages for a new server.

`apt-get install mysql-server openjdk-7-jre-headless tomcat7 tomcat7-admin jsvc apache2 ntp subversion`

As you can see it installs Java 7, but Java 6 is also installed because `tomcat7` (indirectly) depends on it. I'm pretty sure I can run Tomcat 7 with Java 7, so I don't want to install two JREs. How can I prevent Java 6 from being installed?

**Update:** Closer inspection shows that

- `tomcat7`, via `tomcat-common`, depends on
  `default-jre-headless | java6-runtime-headless | java6-runtime | java-6-runtime` (assuming the pipes mean "one of").
- `openjdk-7-jre-headless` provides `java6-runtime-headless`, so that dependency should be met.
- Instead, `default-jre-headless` is installed, which installs Java 6.

Why does that happen? Is it because I install them all at once. Should I split it up into 2 calls?

(Ubuntu 12.04 server, 64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

Use `--nodeps` option with `apt-get` to ignore dependencies being installed.

There is another way is that you download a package and install it with `dpkg` with `--ignore-depends=`package,...

A GUI package manager such as Synaptic, will make you able to select-deselect the dependencies before installation of selected packages.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the line above does not install Java 6. At some point in the development of the script I had `openjdk-7-jre-lib` there, instead of `openjdk-7-jre-headless`, and that one depends on `openjdk-6-jre-lib`, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Create a debian package that "Provides: " the dependency you do not want to install. Install it.

Comment: I found at the dependency should already be provided. Updated the question.